# How to find out rotation angle using dot product

Tags: javascript, rotation, angle, dot-product

I'm trying to rotate a DIV element using the mousemove event on an HTML page. I want to find a rotation angle using the dot product.  I know that it's possible using Math.atan2 too, but I'd like to use dot product in my example.

So far, I tried to implement the following formula:

cos(angle) = dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b))

But the below implementation doesn't work well.
What could be the issue?

Thanks

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/1rosehip/pen/qBrLYLo

```js
const $box = document.getElementById('box');
const shapeRect = $box.getBoundingClientRect();

const shapeCenterX = shapeRect.x + shapeRect.width / 2;
const shapeCenterY = shapeRect.y + shapeRect.height / 2;

/**
 * get vector magnitude
 * @param {Array.<number>} v
 * @return {number}
 */
const length = v => {
  return Math.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2);
};

/**
 * dot product
 * @param {Array.<number>} v1
 * @param {Array.<number>} v2
 * @return {number}
 */
const dot = (v1, v2) => {
  return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1];
};

/**
 * handle rotation
 */
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {

  // vector #1 - shape center
  const centerVector = [shapeCenterX, shapeCenterY];
  const centerVectorLength = length(centerVector);

  // vector #2 - mouse position
  const mouseVector = [evt.pageX, evt.pageY];
  const mouseVectorLength = length(mouseVector);

  // cos(angle) = dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b))
  const radians = Math.acos(dot(centerVector, mouseVector) / (centerVectorLength * mouseVectorLength));
  
  const degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
  const angle = (degrees + 360) % 360;

  $box.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
});
```

```css
#box{
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issues.

(1) The vectors were defined from the wrong origin (top left corner of the page instead of the shape center).

(2) Math.acos returns results in the range range [0,pi] instead of [0,2*pi].
It should be fixed by (360 - degrees) when the mouse moves to the left and passes the shape center.

The codepen with fixed version:
https://codepen.io/1rosehip/pen/JjWwaYE

```js
const $box = document.getElementById('box');
const shapeRect = $box.getBoundingClientRect();

const shapeCenterX = shapeRect.x + shapeRect.width / 2;
const shapeCenterY = shapeRect.y + shapeRect.height / 2;

/**
 * get vector magnitude
 * @param {Array.<number>} v
 * @return {number}
 */
const length = v => {
  return Math.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2);
};

/**
 * dot product
 * @param {Array.<number>} v1
 * @param {Array.<number>} v2
 * @return {number}
 */
const dot = (v1, v2) => {
  return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1];
};

/**
 * handle rotation
 */
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {

  // vector #1 - shape center
  const centerVector = [evt.pageX - shapeCenterX, 0 - shapeCenterY];
  const centerVectorLength = length(centerVector);

  // vector #2 - mouse position
  const mouseVector = [evt.pageX - shapeCenterX, evt.pageY - shapeCenterY];
  const mouseVectorLength = length(mouseVector);

  // cos(angle) = dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b))
  const radians = Math.acos(dot(centerVector, mouseVector) / (centerVectorLength * mouseVectorLength));
  
  let degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
  // const angle = (degrees + 360) % 360;
  
  if(evt.pageX < shapeCenterX){
     degrees = 360 - degrees;
  }

  $box.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
});
```

```css
#box{
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```